# How to make minify compress static file on django website

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I have make new website on django link is here *https://civiqochemicals.com/*

When i m test website on google PageSpeed Insights it show me slow website and error on css js and images file. How to fix ...

Comment: Please *don't*. Django should *not* serve static files, that is inefficient and might even be insecure. Serving static/media files is the work of the web server (like nginx, apache, etc.).

Comment: These will almost certainly outperform Django, even with non-minified versions, for example because it has some advanced caching policy, and requests, don't go through all routing and middleware.